# How to delete a gcloud Dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The Dataflow jobs are cluttered all over my dashboard, and I'd like to delete the failed jobs from my project. But in the dashboard, I don't see any option to delete the Dataflow job. I'm looking for something like below at least,

```
$ gcloud beta dataflow jobs delete JOB_ID
```

To delete all jobs,

```
$ gcloud beta dataflow jobs delete
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible. You cannot delete a Dataflow job. This is something that you could request via the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187168%20status:open) (I've wanted it in the past too).

`gcloud dataflow jobs --help`

> COMMANDS
>
> COMMAND is one of the following:
>
> ```
>  cancel
>     Cancels all jobs that match the command line arguments.
>
>  describe
>     Outputs the Job object resulting from the Get API.
>
>  drain
>     Drains all jobs that match the command line arguments.
>
>  list
>     Lists all jobs in a particular project.
>
>  run
>     Runs a job from the specified path.
>
>  show
>     Shows a short description of the given job.
> ```

Comment: This functionality can be tracked here https://issuetracker.google.com/110798648 
Star the thread (in the left upper side) to get automatic updates on the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

As Graham mentions, it is not possible to delete Dataflow jobs. However, note that you can filter the job list to only show the jobs you care about. For example, `Status:Running,Succeeded` will exclude all failed or cancelled jobs.

[image: Dataflow Job filter]

On the commandline, you can use `--status=(active|terminated|all)`:

```
gcloud beta dataflow jobs list --status=active
```

Comment: the monitoring tool or the console displays data only for the jobs run in last 30 days.